# Jquery cycle plugin - Hover/Mouseout Slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a transparent png in a jquery cycle slideshow. On rollover, it fades from Image A to B. On mouseout, it goes back to A. However, it will not repeat this fade on any rollovers afterwards. Any ideas for this?
Thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('#picroll').cycle({                            
                timeout:.2,
                delay:  0, 
        fx: 'fade',
        continuous: false,
                speed:  300,
                autostop: 1
         }).cycle("pause").hover(function() {
                $(this).cycle('resume');
         },function(){
                $(this).cycle('pause');
         $(this).cycle('resume');
   })
     .mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).cycle(0, 'fade').cycle('play');
      });
    });
</script>

  <div id="picroll"><a href="#"><img src="images/group/PictureA.png" width="114" height="330"/>
  <img src="images/group/PictureB.png" width="114" height="330" /></div>
```

Comment: the hover function is called ?

Comment: The hover function is on #picroll. It's started on page load, then resumed on hover. Does that answer your question. Not too familiar with javascript...

Comment: did you made sure it is called? if you call the resume from a JS console, does it work?

Comment: I've put up the code here so you can see how it works: http://noahortmann.ca/fade.html. It seems to work, but I would just want it to repeat the fade on the next rollover. Is this possible?

Comment: the console says : [cycle] unknown transition: play ; slideshow terminating. So I guess you just need to remove that part

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
$("#picroll").mouseover('
     $("#picroll:nth-child(1)").fadeOut(500);
     $("#picroll:nth-child(2)").fadeIn(500);
');
$("#picroll").mouseout('
     $("#picroll:nth-child(1)").fadeIn(500);
     $("#picroll:nth-child(2)").fadeOut(500);
');
```

Comment: thanks! although i'm getting a syntax error and i'm not sure where it is.

Comment: I've edited my code; made an error. It would be better if you could give the images their own id instead of using the nth-child selector.